# Is it possible to make Windows 10 notifications usable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications

I want to use Windows 10 notifications but in their default state they are pretty much useless. They disappear after 5s without any possibility to review them in a history. You can extend the visibility of notifications to 5min but this option doesn't seem to work and the notifications still disappear after 5s.

I don't want notifications to disappear at all, I want to be able to view the notifications until I acknowledged them. Is something like this currently even possible?

Comment: Try Windows 10 Settings, System, Focus Assist,  Turn Focus Assist ON and enable the option "Show a summary .... of what I missed"

Comment: Not ideal but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want notifications to disappear at all, I want to be able to
> view the notifications until I acknowledged them. Is something like
> this currently even possible?

There are settings to help with this issue. You cannot do exactly as you wish to do, but these settings will help.

Go to Windows 10 Settings, System, Focus Assist.

Turn Focus Assist ON and enable the setting  "Show a summary of what I missed when Focus Assist was on"

[image: Focus Assist Settings]

Comment: I noticed another issue with that. Firefox notifications will not show up at all in focus mode.

Comment: Interesting .  I use Chromium Edge in Windows and Firefox only in Linux.

Comment: The other issue I have with this approach is that it disables notifications and only makes them visible in the history. I would like to have both.

Comment: I will keep looking around but there are some limits to Focus Assist built in. Same on my Windows 11 machines.

Comment: Another half baked idea from Microsoft.